# How to re-generate createRefs in componentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

Right now I'm working on a component that needs references to scroll to specific items. However when the component updates all my refs become null. Now I know this is actually intentional behavior because of memory leaks (etc.) but I don't care in this case.

Right now all my create ref code is being called in the constructor, but when I try and recreate the refs they're always null.

I generate the refs in the constructor of my component:

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.eventRefs = props.events.map(() => React.createRef());
    this.scrollRef = React.createRef();
    this.mapRef = React.createRef();
  }
```

When I try to look at those same refs later:

```js
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Even if I recreate the refs here
    // All those values set above are equal to { current: null }
  }
```

Comment: Where are you calling your refs for dom access?

Comment: Inside an inside an `onMouseOver` event. But they're also set to null in `componentDidUpdate` before that event ever gets fired.

Comment: Can you show code?

Comment: Thanks, but I have one more question. Where you set those refs to jsx html elements?

Comment: Found the solution, but I was just using regular `ref={this.scrollRef}` style stuff nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution is to not generate the refs in the `constructor` or update them in `componentDidUpdate` but to create the references before rending:

```js
  render() {
    this._createRefs();

    return ( /* ... */ );
  }
```